# What determines app auto start on boot in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

In my application, there's a feature that allows users to dial a specific number and brings up an activity to front. I have the following receiver, and the **only** receiver registered in AndroidManifest.xml.

```xml
<receiver android:name="com.example.myapp.OutgoingCallListener" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Please note there's no `BOOT_COMPLETED intent` or `service`.

Now here's the thing I couldn't figure out. When I reboot my device, go check the `Running Apps`, my application is not listed there. But, if I dial the specific number, my application starts and the activity is brought to front.

My question is: If the app is not a service, and not started on boot, how could it recieve intent from Android? That is, in my case, how could my app listen to `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` while it's not started at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered in the manifest is always capable of responding to a matching broadcast. If your process is not running for any reason, Android will start up a process for you.

Comment: OK, in plain words, can I understand that by "Android checks the application's BroadcastReceiver and marks it in a list during app installation. And when an intent is triggered, Android will go check the list and match apps." Is that correct?

Comment: @user1643156: More or less. The details are a bit more complicated, but you have the general idea.

Comment: I just downloaded a Process Manager, which monitors all tasks (where the stock App Manager shows only a list of started apps). Now I can see that my app is running in background even though it's not started.

Comment: Your username looks familiar at first sight...and I just realized...commonsware.com. Thanks for the answer.